# Is this a PHP issue? Undefined variable: rawHTML error on WP migration

Tags: php, wordpress, centos

I get a TON of these errors when I migrated my WP to a VirtualBox Centos machine:

> Undefined variable: rawHTML

Is my PHP not set up correctly? How can I tell? I'm quite lost because most of the site appears to be normal.

I'm migrating from a PHP 5.2 to a 5.3 Centos server.

Additional errors include:

> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0!

and

> Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: those bugs have probably always been there, but you had display errors turned off. errors are most likely due to outdated plugins or something like that.

Comment: in your production environment, you should have display errors turned off, but in your test environment, they should be turned on.

Comment: so should I worry about these errors if they don't seem to present a problem on production? my goal is to speed up the site.

Comment: I personally would track them down and fix them. Are you the developer of the site, or just someone who changed the server? If you are the developer, you should find out why these are happening and fix them. If not, you should pass the errors to the dev.

Comment: Just because you can't see an problem, doesn't mean there isn't one.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly that error has always been there, but PHP on the old machine was set to not show errors at Notice level. Compare the values for error_reporting in php.ini on the two machines.

It may also be that now you have display_errors set to on, whereas the old machine sent the to the log file, or didn't report them.